# How to create registration form in Titanium using android and pass data to another form?

Tags: android, titanium

Please give me idea how to create a registration form in titanium and pass fill up the registration data from that form to another form .

Comment: What do you have working so far?  Please post example code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: a question related to registration form. when i am fill up name,add etc... all the information which is fill up by me. it will display on another page. please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a sample code for registration. I have created an additional file 'success.js' in the resource folder, shows the second window. Please try the following code

Write these line in the app.js file

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 width : 'auto',
 height: 'auto',
 backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
});

var txtName = Ti.UI.createTextField({
 top   : '25%',
 width : '75%',
 height: '35',
 hintText : 'Name'
});

win1.add(txtName);

var txtAddress = Ti.UI.createTextField({
 top   : '35%',
 width : '75%',
 height: '40',
 hintText : 'Address'
});

win1.add(txtAddress);


var btnRegister = Ti.UI.createButton({
 top : '55%',
 width : '50%',
 height : '35',
 title  : 'Register'
});

 win1.add(btnRegister);

 win1.open();
 btnRegister.addEventListener('click', function(){

 var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  width : 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
  url  : 'success.js'
});

 win2.name = txtName.value;
 win2.address = txtAddress.value; 
 win2.open();
});
```

// Write the following lines in the success.js file

```
var win2 = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var name = win2.name;
var address = win2.address;
var lblName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  top  : '30%',
  width : '75%',
  height : 'auto',
  color  : 'yellow',
  backgroundColor : 'blue',
  text : name,
  textAlign : 'center'
 });

var lblAddress = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  top  : '40%',
  width : '75%',
  height : 'auto',
  color  : 'yellow',
  backgroundColor : 'blue',
  text : address,
  textAlign : 'center'
 });

 win2.add(lblName);
 win2.add(lblAddress);
```

now complile the code and run. It worked with me. Try it

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of making the window transparent?

Comment: i am create a demo in which i will use it.

Comment: okay you can set the window property opacity between 0.1 and 1.0, to make the window semi transparent and if you want to make the window transparent completely set the backgroundColor property to 'transparent'. Vijay, If you got the answer for your question please mark it as accepted

Comment: Mr. Andand Have you any idea  about how to create a Like a Marque in titanium in which text continous work from left to right and right to left. please give me idea or a demo.

Comment: Mr.Vijay, Can you let me know whether you're satisfy with my answer on your question?

Comment: HI... Mr. Anand I am satisfy with your anser

Comment: @Vijay: Please put the tick mark in the answer, if it solved your problem.